# Find all instances of word from a list of words across my entire codebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm wondering is it possible to search through my entire codebase to find instances of keywords I pass as an array.

Currently I'm using the search feature in vscode but this only allows one word at a time and I've got hundreds.

I'm happy to use whatever there is out there, vscode extension, npm package, something I'm able to code myself, just anything to speed this process up.

The codebase I'm wanting to search through is React based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use a regular expression (available natively in the search menu of vscode)

[image: Regex option]

Then you can write your query as a regex, for example like this

```
word1|word2|word3
```

You can use a quick algorithm to transform your array into this, so you can just copy paste the result

```
array.join('|')
```

Comment: Sorry for literally duplicating your answer. We were answering at the exact same time and wrote the same thing ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ lol

Comment: Same here, oops!

Comment: That was unexpected

Comment: Thanks for such a quick and bountiful response everyone :D

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using regular expressions. Inside of the vscode project search do this:

```
keyword1|keyword2|keyword3
```

and make sure that you have regular expression mode turned on:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex search in VSCode to find a list of search terms.

**Example:**

```
(wordOne|wordTwo)
```

Add regex word boundaries in order to match only that word without matching partial words (ie. the word `data` will match only `data` and not `newData`, for instance):

```
\b(wordOne|wordTwo)\b
```

Remember to turn on regex matching for the search!

Comment: It's amazing how all 3 of us answered the *exact* same thing lol

Comment: Well at least op knows what to do now :D